# Raname script for Python in Maya

Tags: python, scripting, maya, pymel

I have this script and I want to parent the controls together and rename the icons.  Right now it names the groups, but doesn't name the controls or parents them.  Can anyone help me?

```
def priming(*args):
    jointChain = pm.ls(sl = True, dag = True)
    jointChain.pop(-1)

    ori = raw_input()
    systemName = raw_input()
    suffix = "prime"

    prime1Name = "{0}_{1}_00_{2}1".format(ori, systemName, suffix)
    prime2Name = "{0}_{1}_00_{2}2".format(ori, systemName, suffix)

    pm.select(cl = True)

    for jointName in jointChain:

        primeIcon = pm.circle(nr = [1, 0, 0])

        groupOne = pm.group(em = True, n = prime1Name)  
        groupTwo = pm.group(em = True, n = prime2Name)

        pm.parent(groupTwo, groupOne)

        pm.parent(primeIcon, groupTwo)

        tempConstraint = pm.parentConstraint(jointName, groupOne, mo = False)

        pm.delete(tempConstraint)

        pm.makeIdentity(primeIcon, a = True, t = 1, r = 1, s = 1)

        tempConstraintTwo = pm.orientConstraint(primeIcon, jointName, mo = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of your code. This one parents the groups and the controllers and also names them based on a naming scheme (that you can tweak if needed):

```py
def priming(*args):
    jointChain = pm.ls(sl=True, dag=True)
    print jointChain
    jointChain.pop(-1)
    print jointChain

    ori = raw_input()
    systemName = raw_input()
    suffix = "prime"

    prime1Name = "{0}_{1}_00_{2}1".format(ori, systemName, suffix)
    prime2Name = "{0}_{1}_00_{2}2".format(ori, systemName, suffix)
    iconNameBase = "your_icon" # Your icon naming scheme here

    pm.select(cl=True)

    last_created_icon = None
    name_index = 1
    for jointName in jointChain:
        # Modify your iconName with every iteration here
        # Sample scheme: your_icon_1, your_icon_2 etc.
        iconName = "%s_%i" % (iconNameBase, name_index)
        name_index += 1
        primeIcon = pm.circle(nr=[1, 0, 0], n=iconName)
        groupOne = pm.group(em=True, n=prime1Name)  
        groupTwo = pm.group(em=True, n=prime2Name)
        pm.parent(groupTwo, groupOne)
        pm.parent(primeIcon, groupTwo)
        tempConstraint = pm.parentConstraint(jointName, groupOne, mo=False)
        pm.delete(tempConstraint)
        pm.makeIdentity(primeIcon, a=True, t=True, r=True, s=True)
        tempConstraintTwo = pm.orientConstraint(primeIcon, jointName, mo=True)

        if last_created_icon:
            pm.parent(groupOne, last_created_icon)

        last_created_icon = primeIcon
```